# Как правильно экспортировать модел в Blender?

Tags: unity3d, blender, моделирование

Решил создать свою модельку для Unity в блендере.
[image: Вот сама моделька в Blender]

Но когда загрузил её в Unity (в формате obj) получилось вот это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы моделька экспортировалась в своём изначальном виде.

Comment: Это она и есть,

Comment: моделька и есть в том виде в котором импортировалась. А вот с материалами и текстурами нужно поигратся.